# Ansible 'assert' module and '"changed": false'

Tags: ansible, assert, idempotent

The following basic playbook uses the `assert` module :

```
---
# ANSIBLE_LOCALHOST_WARNING=false ansible-playbook test.yml
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - assert:
      that:
        - 1 == 1

  - assert:
      that:
        - 1 == 2
...
```

and outputs :

```
TASK [assert] ********************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All assertions passed"
}

TASK [assert] ********************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "1 == 2",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "Assertion failed"
}
```

1. What's the meaning of the `changed` line, since it's `false`, whatever the `assert` succeeds or fails ? I guess this is because Ansible tasks have to have a `changed` status, and `assert` tasks, since they just check things and make no change, receive `false` as a default option. Am I right ?
2. In my team, the routine to check for idempotency is to count the `changed` lines from the Ansible execution logs. But these `"changed": false` output by `assert` tasks are false positives. Is there a way to silence them (i.e. prevent `assert` from outputting a `changed` line) ? Otherwise, the workaround would be to count `"changed": true,` lines rather than just `changed`.

Comment: 1) yes you are right. As a counter example, shell/command will always report changed: true if you don't manage "changed_when" on the task 2) yes you should count only the `changed  | bool`or `task_registered_result is changed` to check for idempotency if need be from outside of ansible. `ansible(-playbook)` reports idempotency by itself.